# How to create files with different names using the least amount of processing power in Swift?

Tags: swift, performance, file, memory-management

I am writing a video app that records video only when triggered and at the end of all the recordings merges the recordings together into one at the end.

I was just wondering if there is process in swift to make sure the name of the next file of a recording is different than the previous one? I know ways of doing this that are fine, but I am a bit of a memory freak and was wondering if swift has a built in answer to this problem?

Edit: 
This works with the variable filenamechanger. I just was wondering if there is an even better way.

```
 var filenamechanger = 0

            if motiondetected == true {
                do{
                let documentsDir = try FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)
                filenamechanger += 1 //name changer

                let fileURL = URL(string:"test\(filenamechanger).mp4", relativeTo:documentsDir)!
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at:fileURL)
                } catch {
                }

                self.movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL:fileURL, size:Size(width:480, height:640), liveVideo:true)
                self.camera.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieOutput
                self.camera --> self.movieOutput!
                self.movieOutput!.startRecording()
                    sleep(3)
                self.camera.audioEncodingTarget = nil
                self.movieOutput = nil
                motiondetected = false

                }
                catch{
                    "recording didn't work"


                }
            }
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with what you have tried and explain your concerns with it. Also note that it would seem you are prematurely worrying about performance. Test and analyze to be sure if there is a real problem or not.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy, I edited my question to show what I have tried. I just was wondering if there is a quicker way instead of needing to change a variable and add another step. Also I saw your bio. That is really cool you worked with BASIC.